# Can you deploy/manage non-CLR procedures with VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to store just .sql versions of your stored procedures in a project, then deploy them automatically to a SQL server? Every article I find talks about using a SQL CLR project, writing them in C#, then deploying them, which I can't do because my DBA won't enable CLR.

I am just looking for a way to add them to my solution so that they can be managed in svn, but not have to manually deploy them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio Premium Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/premium/overview) and upper allows you to create [Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx), store it under Source Control, Refactor and many other goodies..

Here is a great training on the subject by PluralSight:

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/Course/Toc.aspx?n=vs-db

And here is a blog post about it:

http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/08/manage-database-projects-with-visual-studio-2010/